# How to export Analytics from dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm working in Dialogflow Essentials. I need to be able to export specific analytics.

When i open the Dialogflow analytics there are not how to export data

Answer (score 0):

The way you do that is to enable the "Log interactions to Dialogflow" and "Log interactions to Google Cloud".

You can enable it on the Dialogflow Essentials console, accessing "Settings " and then "General". You'll find both options in the "Log Settings".

[image: see attached image]