# Export Detailed Analytics from DialogFlow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, google-analytics, export, dialogflow-es

I am looking to export analytics from DialogFlow. Specifically, I'd like to know how my users are using the chatbot, what things they are asking it and where. The Analytics Page on dialogflow has some of this information in the form of percentages, which is what I want, but there's 2 issues with that:

1. The data is a bit skewed as 99% usage is for the welcome page, which always appears, so that data is not useful.
2. I need to make a report for higher-ups that contains this information, which requires me to export it, but I do not see an option to do so.

I see you can use gcp logs explorer to look at this as well, but then I need to filter only the dialogflow logs and make sense of them and analyze percentages from there, that just seems like a step back, and the documentation for that is just confusing.

How can I filter, sort and export this data to get what I actually want without the noise?

This question: ([How to export Analytics from dialogflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68898635/how-to-export-analytics-from-dialogflow)) seems to be asking a similar thing, but the answer given only tells how to turn on logging, which I already have done. I'm looking to export these logs in a useful form.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you already turned on the Log interactions to Diagflow.

The next step is filtering the logs you want on Logs Explorer. You can find more information on how to filter logs by checking the [Logging Query Language](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/building-queries) documentation article.

After you filtered the logs you would like to store and analyze, the next step is routing these logs to a BigQuery dataset. I find this the best suitable destination for your scenario as you can use big data analysis capabilities on the stored logs.

For doing so, you can follow these steps:

- Create a Log Sink with the following attributes:

  - Sink destination: BigQuery table
  - Build inclusion filter: paste your query with the desired logs

You can find more detailed information [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2).

The next step is analyzing the information on the dataset. For doing so, you can process SQL-like queries that will provide crucial information towards data analysis. You can find all information on doing so, along with other BigQuery features [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-overview).

Hope this information helped! :)